# No linebreaks between fields in email from a Wagtail form

Tags: wagtail

I have a site made using [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io) and have a Page containing [a form](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/forms/index.html) on it that has a few fields: Name, Email, Organization and Message.

It submits successfully and sends an email to the address specified in the Wagtail admin, but the email I receive doesn't have any linebreaks between the fields:

> Your name: Phil Your email: me@example.com Your organization: My organisation Your message: Just testing message sending!
>
> Hello there!

As you can see, it *does* include linebreaks that are in the message field (a Multi-line text field).

I guess I could [add a custom `send_mail` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#custom-send-mail-method) but I'd have thought linebreaks would appear by default. Is there something simple I need to change?

Comment: FWIW, I've just tested this locally (albeit only with the 'dummy' email backend) and the line breaks are appearing as expected... have you tried sending the email to a recipient with a different email client, to confirm that this isn't the receiving end behaving oddly?

Comment: @gasman Ah, yes! And looking at the source of the email in Apple Mail, the plaintext version is fine, but the HTML version doesn't have any `<br>`s to replace the linebreaks (only `<p>`s for double linebreaks). And, looking at the Wagtail code, I'm guessing the HTML version was created by Sendgrid (which I'm using for email sending), from the plaintext version, rather than Wagtail.

Comment: Yes, Sendgrid's the culprit. If no HTML version is supplied, it creates one by default. Solutions here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/cross-platform-html-design/#controlling-converted-plain-text-email-output Sorry for the false Wagtail alarm!